# How can I rename a network in Windows 8?

Tags: networking, windows-8

I recently replaced my home router, and now Windows 8 seems to think that the main Ethernet network is called "Network 2", when it used to simply be called "Network".

[image: Network and Sharing Center]

[image: Networks]

There is no "Network" anymore; only "Network 2".

My question is: **How can I rename "Network 2" to "Network"?** It's a small annoyance, but annoying nonetheless. I've tried Googling the problem, but the only purported solutions I've found apply to Windows 7, and not Windows 8.

The closest thing I can find is the ability to rename the network in Network Connections, but I can only rename the "Ethernet" name (which doesn't seem to be used anywhere else in Windows), but I can't change the subname "Network 2".

[image: Network Connections rename]

I've also tried searching the registry for "Network 2", but there are no instances found.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not an annoyance, it's a security issue too. There are multiple WiFi networks in our work building (and on campus). They just show up as "Network X" (X=1,2,3...). How about more obvious clarify to WHAT a user is currently connected too...

Comment: Dunno if this works for Windows 8, but for Windows 7 you can just do this http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/24683-network-name-icon-change.html

Answer (score 51, accepted):

OK! I finally just found this related (but slightly different) question and answer, and I was able to solve my problem using the registry keys provided in that answer:

[Remove a known network from Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/517414/remove-a-known-network-from-windows-8)

Note: I don't think this question should be closed as a duplicate, because it's a bit different, and the solution is a bit simpler. You don't need to delete your new network, you can simply rename a few values.

## How to rename "Network 2" to "Network":

Open regedit and browse to each of the following registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Nla\Cache\Intranet
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\Unmanaged
```

1. Dig through all of the keys, subkeys, and values under each of those keys, and look for any instances of "Network" and "Network 2" in the values. (I only found instances under the 2nd and 3rd keys — not the 1st — but I'm leaving that key in for completeness.)
2. Delete any keys (i.e., the whole key "folder") that contain values set to "Network". These are the registry entries for your old network, which is no longer in use.
3. Find all of the keys that contain values set to "Network 2", and rename those values to "Network". These are the registry entries for your new network.
4. Reboot your computer.

*Voila!* No more "Network 2".

Comment: I can confirm it worked for me - well researched.

Comment: Yo Microsoft! Can you add some GUI elements to rename and reclassify networks. Sucks to break into registry editors on a tablet. Hmm, ok. Thanks.

Comment: This is a nice find, but I wonder how "safe" this is? What are the dependencies?

Comment: @davor: That's a valid question, but unfortunately it's a question that I can't answer. For me, the annoyance of the "Network 2" name was worth the risk of hacking around the registry. That said, I've been happily using this solution for over a year, and I haven't had any issues at all. So, at least in my experience, it seems pretty safe.

Comment: Upvote for sweet solution. I guess Microsoft tries to simplify things, but ends up bugging people like me. (can't stand that 2 at the end).

Answer (score 47):

Hit <kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> => open the Run prompt => enter `secpol.msc`

Navigate to: Network List Manager Policies

Choose your Network name from the right pane. Here you can change the NAME, if is PRIVATE or not, The ICON of the network and so on

You can also set the defaults - Microsoft should have set these defaults before shipping Windows 8.1

Comment: But you can not delete not-connected networks?

Comment: Changing it in "Local Security Policy" changes the name right away (no reboot needed), but, it does not update the aforementioned registry keys, so you can "unset" the name here and it reverts back. For the curious, this name gets stored in a key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\

Comment: Worked for me in Windows 10.

Comment: there is a user rights there option when editing properties there to rename it that says "User can change name". From what UI is user supposed to change the name though?