# Get default Windows network name string on cmd.exe

Tags: networking, cmd.exe

Windows automatically identifies connected networks and names them as `Wireless Network`, `Wired Network 2` or `windows.domain.tld` in case of domain joined systems. Is there any command to get the string of the connected network that Windows has detected it's on?

**UPDATE**

After trying @Bob's answer, I've noticed it the output lists a line for every network it's connected to:

```
> Get-NetConnectionProfle | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
Wired Connection
Wireless Connection 3
VPN Name
```

By default Windows only uses one of the connected networks for all traffic, such as only wired connection even as wireless is connected as well, and only the VPN if connected. What do I do to get only the name string of the default network?

Comment: There appears to be some confusion about what you are actually expecting as output (so I deleted my answer). It's now undeleted so please check if it meets your needs. It outputs the name of the currently "Connected" network connection.

Comment: You have a typo...missing an i in "Get-NetConnectionProfle"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find default interface, you have to find default route with lowest metric. You can do this with following PowerShell code:

```
$DefaultIPv4InterfaceIndex=
Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 0.0.0.0/0|
Sort-Object {$_.RouteMetric+(Get-NetIPInterface -AssociatedRoute $_).InterfaceMetric}|
Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex

$DefaultIPv6InterfaceIndex=
Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix ::/0|
Sort-Object {$_.RouteMetric+(Get-NetIPInterface -AssociatedRoute $_).InterfaceMetric}|
Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty InterfaceIndex
```

Note, that default interface for IPv4 and for IPv6 can be different. Now, as you have interface index, you can use `Get-NetConnectionProfile` to get network name:

```
(Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex $DefaultIPv4InterfaceIndex).Name
(Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex $DefaultIPv6InterfaceIndex).Name
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Great answer. Could make it a one-liner with a filter, but that's not too important.

Comment: I successfully used it in my first PowerShell script ever. Thank you very much for this snippet!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use PowerShell, as of Windows Server 2012 R2/Windows 8.1 it has a [`Get-NetConnectionProfile`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj899566%28v=wps.630%29.aspx) cmdlet, and you can extract just the network name with the following:

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

You can run this on earlier versions of Windows by installing PowerShell 4.0 ([Windows Management Framework 4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855)).

You can run this from the legacy Command Prompt by passing it into PowerShell with `powershell -c`.

You could also access the registry keys directly, though I'm unsure of how you'd figure out which one is the current one: [How can I rename a network in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/550178/how-can-i-rename-a-network-in-windows-8)

Comment: I just need to get the name for scripting, that is to say to figure out if the system is connected to my LAN and, if not connected to LAN, connect to the VPN that does. I think either this command or the one you edited out would be enough (provided they work). I'll accept the answer when I get to test it out (not on a Windows system currently).

Comment: On a related note, I also [asked](http://superuser.com/questions/984690/connect-to-l2tp-ipsec-username-password-psk-on-cmd-exe) how it is possible to connect to an L2TP/IPsec VPN on `cmd.exe` for the same script. If you know anything, please weigh in.

Comment: Bit of a problem your command—it lists a line for every network it's connected to, i.e. one line for wireless, another for wired and a third for VPN.

Comment: I'm changing the question to the string of default network the system is connected to. Even if both wired and wireless is connected, Windows by default uses only one for all it's connections, and similarly uses only the VPN when connected.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to `Controlpanel > Network & Internet > Network & Sharing center` it will show `active networks`.

You can also go from `Network & Sharing center` and click `Edit Settings` for the network card. It will show all networks with the relative status.

Note: the setting names can be mistranslated from my Danish PC.

Comment: I specifically asked for `cmd.exe`, sorry.