# Windows 8.1 NIC Exists in Two Networks at once

Tags: networking, virtualbox, windows-8.1, ethernet

My ethernet adapter is showing in two windows network locations at once. How is this possible and how do I remedy it?

## The ethernet adapter is configured:

```
IP:      192.168.10.100
subnet:  255.255.0.0
gateway: 192.168.10.102
```

## The virtualbox network is configured:

```
IP:      192.168.20.1
subnet:  255.255.255.0
gateway: 192.168.20.1
```

The ethernet is used for a peer-peer direct connect network via a crossover cable. So the gateway is simply the ip of the other machine. Regardless, I have configured the two nics on the same machine to have different subnets so they won't conflict.

[image: Ethernet exists in two windows network locations]

Comment: The first subnet mask `255.255.0.0` is wrong, needs to be 255.255.255.0. In the current version, it also covers the second network!

Comment: Why does it "have to be" `255.255.255.0`? I'm able to network just fine with the subnet as is.

Comment: The subnet mask isn’t wrong, just unusual. But he is right about the overlapping: 192.168.20.0/24 is fully contained within 192.168.0.0/16. This *might* have caused the issue.

Comment: The smaller subnet mask of the 192.168.10.x network fully comprises the 192.168.20.x network, this means, that e.g. 192.168.20.99 is reachable from BOTH networks - which is not what you want!

Comment: Duly noted. Thanks for the information guys. Looks like I'm going to need to do more reading on network configuration!

Answer (score 0):

Because windows 8 is so user friendly I took the easy route and just uninstalled all the networking drivers. Went into the registry per [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/517414/remove-a-known-network-from-windows-8) and deleted all network locations. Then I uninstalled the bridged virtualbox virtual adapter. Disabled the virtualbox host-only virtual adapter. Installed the intel ethernet drivers. Then because there is no "right-click" on network connections I did: charms > settings > change pc settings > network > connections THEN left click the connection, turn on Find devices so that the network goes private. Then I re-enabled the virtualbox host-only adapter. Windows 8 is such a PO$.

End result:
[image: Fixed bootleg windows 8 networking]

As you can see now the adapters are on separate networks and not duplicated.

Update: I'm sure this will all break when I re-install the virtualbox bridged network adapter. :-)