# Unexplained password prompt on Windows 8.1 Pro, SharePoint?

Tags: windows-8.1, passwords, sharepoint, office365

I'm trying to solve a bit of a mystery that seems connected to SharePoint on my Windows 8.1 Pro (via Pro Pack upgrade) machine. To my knowledge I have never intentionally installed any SharePoint software. I've worked with it before and can't stand it.

If I boot to Windows and my internet connection isn't available I see this prompt:

[image]

I never see this when the internet connection is available. I've tried examining the Task Manager when this prompt is shown to see if I can figure it out but this hasn't turned up anything unexpected.

I have Office 365 installed, Avira, and a whole lot more - not having a clue what's causing this I don't have any idea what is relevant to mention.

I haven't tried a password as 1) I don't know if I've ever set up an account for whatever this is and 2) I have no idea what it would do with any passwords I provide (I'm confident my machine is clean but why risk it).

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: HAve a look in your list of networks to see if you can see one called sharepoint. Look in Network and Sharing Centre and Network Connections. The system is trying to connect to a network called "SharePoint". Do you have an old version of groove.exe installed (groove became Onedrive for Business).

Comment: Interesting, I do have OneDrive 2013 for Business that I think came with Office 365. I've been trying to eradicate it but apparently this isn't possible so it's just disabled everywhere I can find it. I looked at the list of known networks using the method here http://superuser.com/questions/517414/remove-a-known-network-from-windows-8 and there are two / one with two names that I don't recognise: "volume1" and "150.201.1.3". All other networks look familiar, however I see nothing with the name SharePoint

Comment: ODfB is called groove.exe and you will find it in your startup, look in task manager. Should be able to disable from there. For the others, make sure Windows Update is up to date, create a system restore point, reboot then delete the odd networks and see if that helps. If not restore back. Doesn't take long.

Comment: groove is not listed for startup. I checked services.msc but saw nothing hinting at groove or OneDrive

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by any application trying to make an active network connection.  The Office clients will make active attempts to access O365.  Any of those applications that are running can give you that prompt.  The first place to look is Outlook, Lync, and the OneDrive for business, but be aware that Word, Excel, and PowerPoint can also request this connection depending on what you opening or doing with the applications.

Comment: It'll be the OneDrive for Business client as the Business side is a SharePoint backend. We use it and our users often see this.